How to register a new key for a docker registry
I created a docker image some time ago and used a key to sign it.
But now I forgot the password for the key, so I tried creating a new key, which worked perfectly.
But I can't remember how I got the key registered.
The following is from the official docker documentation under https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/.
docker trust signer add --key cert.pem jeff registry.example.com/admin/demo

but when I create a key using
docker trust key generate somename

I only get a .key(private key) and a .pub(public key) file, but no .pem file.
Is there any way I can convert a .pub file to a .pem file.

I believe this is a mistake in the documentation (or perhaps pem works as well), but I tested this right now and it works like:
docker trust key generate nmishin

And after that, you can add signer to the docker repository, like:
docker trust signer add --key nmishin.pub nmishin registry.example.com/admin/demo

Also I found a couple of articles that demonstrate the use of pub key also:
hackernoon and trendmicro
